# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' when trying to use df.diff()

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am getting a value error when running the df.diff() code in my program. My goal is to get a new column which displays the change between rows in the ClientId_Count column.

I have tried converting the int64 variables to float variables and there is still an issue. I am wondering if this is possibly because the TimePeriod column is a string variable? If so how can I use df.diff() to only compute the differences on the ClientId_Count column?

[image]

The code I used to get this data frame is as follows ( I dont think the queries matter but I included them just in case):

```
a = '''SELECT distinct [ClientId]
  FROM [GB_Msi_P1].[dbo].[table]
  where EffectiveDate >= '2018-11-01 00:00:00.000' '''

client = pd.read_sql(a, sql_conn)


b = '''select a.TimePeriodId, a.ClientId, a.BenefitCode, a.TerminationDate, a.EffectiveDate 
from [GB_Msi_P1].[dbo].[table] as a
where EffectiveDate >= '2018-11-01 00:00:00.000' and a.BenefitCode in ('25', '26', '29', '46', '66') 
order by EffectiveDate desc'''

benefit = pd.read_sql(b, sql_conn)
benefit['ClientId'].nunique()

new_clients = pd.merge(client, benefit, on = ['ClientId']).drop(columns=['TerminationDate'], axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
new_clients['TimePeriodId'] = new_clients['TimePeriodId'].astype(str)

#count clients by distinct name of client
new_clients_optional = new_clients.groupby(['TimePeriodId'])[['ClientId']].count().rename(columns={'ClientId': 'ClientId_Count'}).reset_index()


#display as discrete difference bwteen each time period Id
discrete_change_NCO = new_clients_optional.diff()
```

this gives the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: We can't answer several of your secondary questions, because you failed to provide a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste your posted code into our own Python IDEs and reproduce your problem.  Hard-code a small data frame; provide the *entire* error message, including trace-back.  Trace your questionable data types and values.

Comment: will edit and send back out. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is almost certainly that you applied `diff` to inapplicable columns.  We can't tell what your data types are, as you failed to check them in your code, and didn't give us the actual data frame.

As you've suggested, the way to properly design this is to apply `diff` to only the column for which you need that data.  Extract the column as a new frame or view; apply `diff` to that.

```
temp = new_clients_optional["ClientId_Count"]
discrete_change_NCO = temp.diff()
```

You will likely want to fold these lines together, and then into other code.